# Convert yyyymmdd(int type) to date

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to use [WEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function so I need a **date** type.

While what I have in db is a **int** type like 20150101 representing 1st,Jan 2015.

I tried `FROM_UNIXTIME` but obviously it is not I want:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(20150101) from dual;
+-------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(20150101) |
+-------------------------+
| 1970-08-22 14:15:01     |
+-------------------------+
```

Do I have a way to convert the yyyymmdd(int) to a date type?

Comment: Why oh why are you not storing this in a DATE, or DATETIME column? Why make life more difficult than it has to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just select it as a `date()` and it converts automatically.

```
SELECT DATE(20150101) FROM dual;
```

Comment: Doesn't convert `19581486` in my version (10.3.32-MariaDB)

Answer (score 5):

`20150101` is not a unix timestamp its in the format `ymd` you need `date_format` to format it

```
mysql> select date_format('20150101','%Y-%m-%d') as date ;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2015-01-01 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select unix_timestamp('2015-01-01');
+------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp('2015-01-01') |
+------------------------------+
|                   1420050600 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME(1420050600) ;
+---------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1420050600) |
+---------------------------+
| 2015-01-01 00:00:00       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT WEEK(
         CONCAT(
           SUBSTR(20150101, 1, 4),
           '-',
           SUBSTR(20150101, 5, 2),
           '-',
           SUBSTR(20150101, 7, 2)
         )
       )
FROM dual
```

... assuming the number of characters will always be 8 (as in `20150101`).